# Navbar for mobile doesn't collapse when link are clicked

Tags: html, css, nav

I am trying to make my code collapse when the links are clicked but it doesn't work.

I tried adding to the  link the data-toggle but in that case, the links do not works.

```
<HTML>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top activate-menu navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#showcase">MyWebsite</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#showcase">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#features">Feature</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#teams">Team</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

</HTML>
```

The output should be that the links in the nav works and the menu closes when one link is clicked.

The current output is the link works yet the menu doesn't collapse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add in html before `</body>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $('.navbar-nav li a').on('click', function(){
          $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('show');
      });

  </script>
```

Comment: before which tag? the <nav>?

Comment: @Alessandro Candeloro bottom of </body>

Comment: thank you! could you edit the answer so that the </body> tag is visible so I can put this answer as the right one? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add this `script`

```
 $(document).off('click', '.navbar-nav a');
 $(document).on('click', '.navbar-nav a', function () {
     //$(".btn-navbar").click(); //bootstrap 2.x
       $(".navbar-toggle").click() //bootstrap 3.x 
  })
```

Comment: I have added a <script> tag in the HTML code at the end of the <nav> is that the right place or should I put it in the main JS file?

Comment: `should I put it in the main JS file?` yes

Comment: still not working... I am adding it to the script.js file on the very beginning

Answer (score 0):

pls add inside head tag

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: pls share your html and css

Comment: CSS is bootstrap 3 what part of the HTML do you need?

Comment: i need to see import files are correct way.. or you can create some example

Comment: you asked about this mobile view or desktop view

Comment: when it goes to the mobile view because desktop doesn't have the dropdown view.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

  $('.navbar-nav li a').on('click', function(){
      $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('show');
  });

  </script>

Comment: @Alessandro Candeloro you should add above code before </body> tag

Answer (score 0):

Add this script.

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.navbar-nav li').click(function(){
  $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('show')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this
Add `data-toggle` and `data-target` in your `li` like this :

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#showcase" 
                   data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#features" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Feature</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#teams" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Team</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Contact</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
```